# Binding issue with List of objects using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple create page which has list of label and date objects, rendered through data from rest api /restapi/reportTypes.
On clicking the Save button I want to save all the data, by calling rest api /restapi/entity.
But all the reportTypes objects are passed through the main object called entity.

**Web page looks like this**

[image]

Javascript

```
crudApp.controller('addController', function($scope, $http, $location) {

    $http.get("/restapi/reportTypes").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.reportTypes = data;
    });

    $scope.add = function() {
        $http.post("/restapi/entity", $scope.entity).success(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
            $location.path('/list');    
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
            console.log("Error : " +statusText);
        });
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="reportType in reportTypes">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">{{reportType.label}}</label>

    <div class="input-group col-md-4">
        <input id="startDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="reportType.startDate"> 
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">NOTES</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" ng-model="entity.notes" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Add" ng-click="add()">
```

For that when I try with below code,

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="reportType in entity.reportTypes">
```

I get error

```
Error: $scope.entity is undefined
```

**Updated:**

Here is my Entity class,

```
public class Entity {

    private List<ReportType> reportTypes;

    private String notes;

    // getter / setters
}
```

Comment: what is `$scope.entity` supposed to represent? it's not defined here in this code before it is used.

Comment: @Claies Thanks I have updated the question.

Comment: ok that's the server class `Entity`, that's not the same as the `$scope` property `entity`;  where are you defining `$scope.entity`?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to do here.  You have an API that is retrieving an array of `reportTypes`, a form that is iterating through each of those and outputting a label and what appears to be a date, followed by an ***unrelated*** single string of notes, and a post method that seems to be posting to an API that wants both of those as a single object.

Comment: I *think* what you are trying to do is retrieve ***all possible report types***, select ***some*** report types for a new entity, along with notes, and pass this new object back to the database.  If that is the case, then your HTML isn't right;  if that isn't the goal, your code isn't really clear enough to make sense of what your intent is here.

Comment: @Claies Thanks exactly that is case as you explained in first part... Can u pls help to point out which part of html is not right ?

Comment: well, if you are trying to select some report types that you want to attach to the new object, the first step would be using a `<select>` rather than iterating through the `reportTypes` in your form.  The second missing piece would be that you need to create the new object on the client first, before you can send anything at all to the server.

Comment: basically, the logic for this controller and HTML don't match at all the action you are trying to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Without having a working Plnkr.co example to look at, I'm going to suggest that the problem is that you don't define $scope.entity in your controller to start with.  Maybe go with something like this?

```
crudApp.controller('addController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.entity = { reportTypes: [] };
```

If you don't define it ahead of time, you'd need some other logic to protect from referencing something that doesn't exist yet.

Perhaps you could have an ng-if conditional (not ng-show, which leaves it in the DOM) around the code with the ng-repeat in it to ensure that it's valid. You need $scope.entity to exist and for it to have a reportTypes property.

```
<div ng-if="entity != undefined && entity.reportType != undefined"
    class="form-group" ng-repeat="reportType in entity.reportTypes">
```